# TypeError: Expected int64, got 1e-07 of type 'float' instead : FasterRCNN TensorFlow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, faster-rcnn

I was trying to replicate [kentaroy47's faster-RCNN](https://github.com/kentaroy47/frcnn-from-scratch-with-keras) by using TensorFlow 2.1.0: However the following error occurs and I cannot find a similar fix on Stack Overflow.

```
Parsing annotation files
Training images per class:
{'Platelets': 234, 'RBC': 2606, 'WBC': 231, 'bg': 0}
Num classes (including bg) = 4
Config has been written to config.pickle, and can be loaded when testing to ensure correct results
Num train samples 193
Num val samples 31
loading weights from pretrain/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
Could not load pretrained model weights. Weights can be found in the keras application folder           https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/keras/applications
no previous model was loaded
Starting training
Epoch 1/50
Exception: in converted code:

/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py:305 train_on_batch  *
    outs, total_loss, output_losses, masks = (
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py:253 _process_single_batch
    training=training))
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py:167 _model_loss
    per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(targets[i], outs[i])
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/losses.py:221 call
    return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/keras_frcnn/losses.py:42 rpn_loss_cls_fixed_num
    return lambda_rpn_class * K.sum(y_true[:, :, :, :num_anchors] * tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_pred[:, :, :, :], y_true[:, :, :, num_anchors:])) / K.sum(epsilon + y_true[:, :, :, :num_anchors])
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/losses.py:994 binary_crossentropy
    K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py:4602 binary_crossentropy
    epsilon_ = _constant_to_tensor(epsilon(), output.dtype.base_dtype)
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py:678 _constant_to_tensor
    return constant_op.constant(x, dtype=dtype)
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py:258 constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py:297 _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_util.py:452 make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
/home/reighns/ObjectDetection/blood_cells_detection/keras-frcnn-ken/fasterrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_util.py:332 _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))

TypeError: Expected int64, got 1e-07 of type 'float' instead.
```

I have seen some posts similar to this, but I was unable to replicate the solutions. I want to try out faster rcnn using tf2.x instead of the tf1.x (which works).

```
def rpn_loss_cls(num_anchors):
def rpn_loss_cls_fixed_num(y_true, y_pred):
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf':
        return lambda_rpn_class * K.sum(y_true[:, :, :, :num_anchors] * tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_pred[:, :, :, :], y_true[:, :, :, num_anchors:])) / K.sum(epsilon + y_true[:, :, :, :num_anchors])
    else:
        return lambda_rpn_class * K.sum(y_true[:, :num_anchors, :, :] * tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_pred[:, :, :, :], y_true[:, num_anchors:, :, :])) / K.sum(epsilon + y_true[:, :num_anchors, :, :])
return rpn_loss_cls_fixed_num
```

I believe the error might be somewhere in the loss.py file

Comment: @deepaksen Hi thanks for the reply, but is there a fix to this code such that it doesn't throw this exception? And one more question, how does reducing the epoch help in this case. Thanks!!

Comment: I have misread epoch thing, that was a log saying that it is first epoch out of 50, my bad. Can you please check loos function once, it could be the bottleneck.

Comment: @deepaksen I believe the error is indeed in the loss function py file. I edited my notebook to add in the likely problematic lines.

Comment: as from the repo it is tested on tf 1.12, what code you are writing will help others to solve the error.

Comment: @deepaksen I'm using tf2.1.0, tf1.x will not throw any errors.

Comment: please try this https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade it will convert the complete tf 1.12 code into tf 2.0